Why does R robustbase and rrcov covMcd compute reweighted step trimming adjustment with actual fraction of outliers?
covMcd and CovMcd in R robustbase and rrcov compute by default a reweighting step.
Reweighting in MCD and similar computes the Mahalanobis distances and the uses a cutoff using the chisquare distribution, computes the standard mean and covariance on the observations with distance below cutoff.
This estimate is corrected for truncating the sample. In the raw MCD estimate this correction is based on the fraction of observations which are in the included set, 50% or slightly larger by default.
However, in the reweighting step, the trimming is metric, which means we are trimming based on a theoretical threshold and not on a fixed fraction of observations.
So, in this case the truncation correction factor should be based on the threshold tail probability and not the actual fraction of observations below the cutoff.
covMcd and CovMcd, as far as I can see, use the actual fraction of observations below the threshold instead of the probability used for the chisquare cutoff.
A consequence of the non-metric trimming correction in R is that the reweighted covariance changes as more outliers are added even if the "good" data never changes. With metric trimming correction the tail probability stays constant and the covariance does not change when additional outliers are added.
background and example
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/9227#issuecomment-2125161686
The question: Is there a reason or justification for R using the observed fraction that I am missing?
Aside:
I currently have to decide whether statsmodels should match the behavior of R in this case. My opinion is not match robustbase and rrcov. However, the robust packages in R are written by experts in the field while for me it is just another topic that I have to figure out just well enough to implement it for statsmodels.
